# Context-free grammar and regular expression

Tags: computer-science

I have got these Context-free grammar/regular expression:

(1) $abba^{*}$

(2) $abb(a+b)^{*}$

(3) $a^{*}ba^{*}ba^{*}$

(4) $S \implies abA \\ A \implies Aa|b$

(5) $S \implies aS|bA \\ A \implies aA|bB \\ B \implies aB|\varepsilon$

(6) $S \implies SA|\varepsilon \\ A \implies abba$

*Note: $\varepsilon$ present empty word ("")*

And these languages:

(A) $\{a, b\}^{*}$

(B) $\{w \in \{a, b\}^{*} | \text{w start with prefix abb} \}$

(C) $\{ abba \}^{*}$

(D) $\{w \in \{a, b\}^{*} | \text{number of b in word is equal to 2} \}$

Which languages are generated by Context-free grammar/regular expression above?

My result:

$
(1) - B - D  \\
(2) - B - D  \\
(3) - - - D \\
(4) - - - D \\
(5) - - - D \\
(6) A - C - 
$

Please can somebody check it?

Comment: Each regular expression or grammar generates a single language.  If I'm reading this correctly, your result states that the language (1) generates is equal to both $ B $ and $ D $, so $ B = D $.  But then your result for (3) contradicts this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression $abba^*$ matches the strings $abb,abba,abbaa,\ldots$, i.e., all strings that start with $abb$ and then have any number of $a$s (including none at all).

- This is not the same as $(A)$, since $(A)$ includes the empty string, which does not match $abba^*$.
- It is not the same as $(B)$, since language $(B)$ includes $abbb$, which does *not* match the string $abba^*$.
- It is not the same as $(C)$, since $(C)$ includes $abbaabba$, which does not match $abba^*$.
- It is not the same as $(D)$, since $(D)$ includes $bb$, which does not match $abba^*$.

In other words, $abba^*$ does not generate any of the four languages.

The regular expression $abb(a+b)^*$, on the other hand, exactly matches $(B)$: every $w\in\{a,b\}^*$ that starts with $abb$ matches $abb(a+b)^*$, and every every word that matches $abb(a+b)^*$ starts with $abb$. It does not match $(D)$, however: $bb$ is in $(D)$ but does not match $abb(a+b)^*$.

You are correct about the regular expression $a^*ba^*ba^*$: it does indeed match language $(D)$ and none of the other three.

Let’s take a look at what the grammar in $(4)$ generates. You can apply the first production only once, and you must begin with it, so every derivation starts $S\Rightarrow abA$. Now you can apply the production $A\to Aa$ $n$ times for some $n\ge 0$, but eventually you must apply $A\to b$ in order to get a terminal word. Thus, every derivation looks like this:

$$S\Rightarrow abA\Rightarrow^n aba^nA\Rightarrow aba^nb\;.$$

The language of this grammar is $\{aba^nb:n\ge 0\}$. This is a subset of languages $(A)$ and $(D)$, but it’s not equal to either of them. For instance, $bb$ is in both $(A)$ and $(D)$, but it’s not in this language.

The grammar in $(5)$ is a bit more complicated, but it’s still not too hard to analyze. Any derivation must begin with some number of applications of $S\to aS$, followed by an application of $S\to bA$; at this point it looks like

$$S\Rightarrow^m a^mS\Rightarrow a^mbA$$

for some $m\ge 0$. We can now apply $A\to aA$ some number of times — say $n$ times — but eventually we must apply $A\to bB$, since the only way to terminate the derivation is to get a $B$. We now have

$$S\Rightarrow^m a^mS\Rightarrow a^mbA\Rightarrow^n a^mba^nA\Rightarrow a^mba^nbB$$

for some $m,n\ge 0$. We can now apply $B\to aB$ some number of times, say $\ell$, and then finally $B\to\epsilon$ to get the derivation

$$S\Rightarrow^m a^mS\Rightarrow a^mbA\Rightarrow^n a^mba^nA\Rightarrow a^mba^nbB\Rightarrow^\ell a^mba^nba^\ell B\Rightarrow a^mba^nba^\ell$$

for some $m,n,\ell\ge 0$. This is exactly the language generated by the regular expression $a^*ba^*ba^*$, so you’re correct in saying that it matches $(D)$ and nothing else.

Finally, the grammar in $(6)$ allows $m$ applications of $S\to SA$ for any $m\ge 0$, but eventually we must apply $S\to\epsilon$. Thus, we can get the derivations

$$S\Rightarrow^mSA^m\Rightarrow A^m$$

for each $m\ge 0$. Each $A$ will then turn into the terminal string $abba$, and we’ll get $(abba)^m$ for any $m\ge 0$. (Note that it doesn’t really matter when we apply $A\to abba$: I chose to do it only after getting rid of the $S$, but you can mix applications of $S\to SA$ and $A\to abba$ without affecting the final result.) The language $\{(abba)^m:m\ge 0\}$ is exactly the $\{abba\}^*$, i.e., $(C)$. It is not language $(A)$, however, since $(A)$ includes *every* possible finite string of $a$s and $b$s, and this language clearly does not: it does not include $b$, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness and detail description in your particular steps... :)

Comment: @user4362081: You’re very welcome.